# Editing text size in title nad legend in ggR (RStoolbox)

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I am using [RStoolbox](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RStoolbox/index.html) and [ggplot2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html) to plot my map. However, I wanted to change the size of text for title and legend size as well. I am using following code for my data.

```
library("RStoolbox")
library("ggplot2")
library("raster")

data(lsat)
pts <- data.frame(x = c(624720, 627480), y = c(-414690, -411090))
endmembers <- extract(lsat, pts)
rownames(endmembers) <- c("water", "vegetation")

## Calculate spectral angles
lsat_sam <- sam(lsat, endmembers, angles = TRUE)
plot(lsat_sam)

## Classify based on minimum angle
lsat_sam <- sam(lsat, endmembers, angles = FALSE)
ggR(lsat_sam, forceCat = TRUE, geom_raster=TRUE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "green"), labels = c("water", "vegetation"))+
  ggtitle("Spectral Angle Mapper")
```

And what I get is:

[image: ggR plot]

Where, title and legend are too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
p <- ggR(lsat_sam, forceCat = TRUE, geom_raster = TRUE) +
     scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "green"),
                       labels = c("water", "vegetation"))+
     ggtitle("Spectral Angle Mapper") +
     theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20),
           legend.title = element_text(size=15),
           legend.text = element_text(size=12))
```

[image: ggR plot]